# Matrix and match

Tags: excel, matrix

I have a dataset in excel, like this and I need to do a match for doing the matrix but I don't know how to do, I can't order (my real dataset it's more complicated than this)

[image: My dataset]

I would like to have an array that multiplies data that are similar to each other. In this case A = A and aa = aa as a condition to then make the final matrix, ideas?
I have used match but it does not execute the function correctly

[image]

Comment: Try this `=SUM(($A2=$G$2:$G$5)*($B2=$H$2:$H$5)*(C2*$I$2:$I$5))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **[SUMPRODUCT()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)** Function --> Simply multiplies arrays together and returns the sum of products.

[image]

• Formula used in cell `K2`

```
=SUM(($A2=$G$2:$G$5)*($B2=$H$2:$H$5)*(C2*$I$2:$I$5))
```

And Fill Down & Fill Right !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Condition 1 | Condition 2 | Condition 1 & Condition 2 | Machine 1 | Machine 2 | Machine 3 |  | Index 1 | Index 2 | Index 1 & Index 2 | Timeprod |  | Machine 1 | Machine 2 | Machine 3 |
| A | aa | =A2&B2 | 0,2 | 1 | 0 |  | B | aa | =H2&I2 | 0,5 |  | =VLOOKUP($C2,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*D2 | =VLOOKUP($C2,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*E2 | =VLOOKUP($C2,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*F2 |
| B | aa | =A3&B3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |  | D | bb | =H3&I3 | 1 |  | =VLOOKUP($C3,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*D3 | =VLOOKUP($C3,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*E3 | =VLOOKUP($C3,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*F3 |
| C | bb | =A4&B4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | C | bb | =H4&I4 | 2 |  | =VLOOKUP($C4,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*D4 | =VLOOKUP($C4,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*E4 | =VLOOKUP($C4,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*F4 |
| D | bb | =A5&B5 | 0 | 0 | 6 |  | A | aa | =H5&I5 | 0,2 |  | =VLOOKUP($C5,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*D5 | =VLOOKUP($C5,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*E5 | =VLOOKUP($C5,$J:$K,2,FALSE)*F5 |